# mysql count distinct syntax

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'm trying to pull a simple count distinct from a table in MySQL. The query is the following:

```
select COUNT (DISTINCT column1) as distinctVol
from table1
```

The error I'm getting is below:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DISTINCT call_reference) as distinctVol
>       from dlr_calls_hist' at line 1 (State:37000, Native Code: 428)

I've already tried in various different ways, but I can try things again upon suggestions, to make sure it's not typo related.

I've also given it a go with an online SS to MySQL converter (I'm used to using SQL Server), which just spat back the same syntax.

Yes, I could potentially output data and import it into SQL Server, which is the final aim of my efforts, but first I would need to create the dataset as the entire db in MySQL is too large with quite a bit of unnecessary info - trying to keep the resource waste to minimum.

All ideas welcome, and thank you in advanZe!

Comment: You need to remove the space between `count` and `(` -> `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`.

Comment: "DISTINCT *call_reference*) as distinctVol" - is that the actual code? Where did "call_reference" come from?

Comment: @Vatev: thanks a million, this was doing my head in!!!!!

Comment: @user2864740: I simply failed to desensitize the error message when I did the post. call_reference is the real name of column1. Schoolboy error, my apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, when using aggregate functions, you can't have whitespace between the function name and the `(`. Change to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column1)
FROM table1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a53d7/2)

Comment: The question is about MySQL, MSSQL is not relevant.